# why base class function wasn't hidden by derived class function with same name

Tags: c++, inheritance

I currently trying to understand the name hiding thing in  C++ inheritance.

I've read this on C++ primer plus, page 744

> In short, redefining inherited methods is not a variation of overloading. If you redefine a function in a derived class, it doesn't just override the base class declaration with same function signature. Instead, it hides all base class methods of the same name, regardless of the argument signatures.

So I tried, here is my two classes, Base, and Derived

```
class Base{
public:
    Base(){
        cout << "Base::Base() called\n";
    }

    virtual ~Base(){}

    virtual void output(int x){
        cout << "Base::output(int x) called\n";
    }

    virtual void output(double x){
        cout << "Base::output(double x) called\n";
    }

    virtual void output(char x){
        cout << "Base::output(char x) called\n";
    }

    virtual void output(string x){
        cout << "Base::ouput(string x) called\n";
    }
};


class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived():Base(){
        cout << "Derived::Derived() called\n";
    }

    virtual ~Derived(){}

    virtual void output(string x){
        cout << "Derived::ouput(string x) called\n";
    }

};
```

According to the book, `void Base::output(string x)` will be redefined, and all other member functions having the same name will be hidden.

But the following two codes tells different stories.

```
Derived* x = new Derived();
x->output(7);
```

This code cannot compile as expected, the error message is

> No viable conversion from 'int' to 'string'

But if I do like this,

```
Base* x = new Derived();
x->output(7);
```

It magically worked, and given following output:

> Base::Base() called
>     Derived::Derived() called
>     Base::output(int x) called

Why this could happen, does the pointer type really influence the lookup?
Btw, this was on Xcode.

Comment: Both of your `output(string)` functions print "Derived::output(string)".

Comment: @kfsone sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

For this code:

```
Derived* x = new Derived();
x->output(7);
```

The compiler will first attempt to resolve the function and it sees that Derived has a function called output.  Once it finds this, the compiler will not look any further.  Then it will resolve the arguments and see that the argument is incorrect and fail.

Either way late binding does not apply here since you are using the Derived class pointer to access a function in the base class.  You would have to up-cast.

For this code:

```
Base* x = new Derived();
x->output(7);
```

The compiler sees that x is Base type which has the function with the argument of an int.  The compiler resolved the function and is set.  If you were overriding the function for polymorphic behavior this would the appropriate usage.

Note that you can call x->output("yes"); and the correct function will be called; which would be the Derived version. Here is where the vtable is used.

For the reason why the compiler does this look into the "Fragile base class problem".

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
Base* x = new Derived();
x->output(7);
```

The functions in `Derived` are not looked up at compile time. Only the functions in `Base` are looked up at compile time. Hence, it works.

When

```
x->output(7);
```

is processed, the only thing we know about type of `x` is that it is a `Base*`. The fact that it really points to a `Derived` object is not taken into account at compile time. At compile time, that call gets resolved to `Base::outout(int)`. Since `Base::output(int)` is not overridden in `Derived`, `Base::output(int)` is executed at run time too. Had there been a `Derived::output(int)`, it would have been executed at run time.

Comment: I thought it should lookup the vtable of Derived, right?

Comment: The vtable is looked up only at run time, that too only for `virtual` member functions. The call to `Base::output(int)` is resolved at compile time. Since `Base::output(int)` is not overridden in `Derived`, `Base::output(int)` is executed at run time.

Comment: Still don't get it, if Base::output(int) is resolved at compile time, does that mean all derived objects pointed by base class pointers will call the base class functions instead of derived ones, since the real type of objects was not taken into account.

Comment: @RSahu Pretty sure that's not how vtables work: http://ideone.com/zA4Byk. If having a Base* pointer didn't use the vtable, to look up functions tagged as virtual, what would the point be of a vtable?

Comment: @kfsone, did I say anything to that effect?

Comment: @Curtis2 the call indeed goes through a vtable since `output(int)` is virtual, but `Derived` doesn't have an entry for `output(int)` so it calls the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pointer type influences the lookup - that's the whole point of having a type. When you define a `Base*`, all the compiler knows is that it will point to an object of type `Base`, the possibility of a `Derived` isn't even considered.

Comment: So that, this base-class-function-hiding thing can be bypassed by using a base class pointer?

Comment: @Curtis2 absolutely. It's only hidden from the perspective of a `Derived`, not a `Base`.

Comment: Ah, I see, even if the actual type of this object is Derived, the Base type pointer makes it look from Base perspective.